# How to add nodes to a multi-level XML from an array?

Tags: php, arrays, xml, xpath, tree

I have an array `$arr=array("A-B-C-D","A-B-E","A-B-C-F")` and my expected output of the XML should be

```
<root>
    <A>
        <B>
            <C>
                <D></D>
                <F></F>
            </C>
            <E></E>
        </B>
    </A>
</root>
```

I have already done the code that creates a new node of the XML for the first array element i.e. A-B-C-D. But when I move to the second element I need to check how many nodes are already created (A-B) and then add the new node based on that in the proper position.

So how do I traverse the XML and find the exact position where the new node should be attached?

my current code looks like this

```
$arr=explode("-",$input);    
$doc = new DomDocument();

$doc->formatOutput=true;
$doc->LoadXML('<root/>');
$root = $doc->documentElement;
$comm = $doc->createElement('comm');
$root->appendChild($comm);
foreach($arr as $a2) {
    $newcomm = $doc->createElement($a2);
    $community->appendChild($newcomm);
    $community=$newcomm;
}
```

Should I use xpath or some other method will be easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stick with using DOMDocument, I've added an extra loop to allow you to add all of the original array items in.  The main thing is before adding a new item in, check if it's already there...

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$set=array("A-B-C-D","A-B-E","A-B-C-F-G", "A-B-G-Q");
$doc = new DomDocument();

$doc->formatOutput=true;
$doc->LoadXML('<root/>');
foreach ( $set as $input ) {
    $arr=explode("-",$input);    
    $base = $doc->documentElement;
    foreach($arr as $a2) {
        $newcomm = null;
        // Decide if the element already exists.
        foreach ( $base->childNodes as $nextElement )   {
            if ( $nextElement instanceof DOMElement 
                    && $nextElement->tagName == $a2 )   {
                $newcomm = $nextElement;
            }
        }
        if ( $newcomm == null )   {
            $newcomm = $doc->createElement($a2);
            $base->appendChild($newcomm);
        }
        $base=$newcomm;
    } 
}
echo $doc->saveXML();
```

As there is no quick way ( as far as I know) to check for a child with a specific tag name, it just looks through all of the child elements for a DOMElement with the same name.

I started using `getElementByTagName`, but this finds any child node with the name and not just at the current level.

The output from above is...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <A>
    <B>
      <C>
        <D/>
        <F>
          <G/>
        </F>
      </C>
      <E/>
      <G>
        <Q/>
      </G>
    </B>
  </A>
</root>
```

I added a few other items in to show that it adds things in at the right place.