# How to solve the issue of multi-level XML using Dom Document in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, xml, dom

I have an array like ip=["A-B-C-D","A-B-E-D","A-B-F-D"]. Now I have to create an XML based on this hierarchy. The expected output of the XML will be.

```
<start>
<comm>
  <name>A</name>
    <comm>
      <name>B</name>
        <comm>
          <name>C</name>
            <comm>
              <name>D</name>
            </comm>
        </comm>
        <comm>
          <name>E</name>
            <comm>
              <name>D</name>
            </comm>
        </comm>
        <comm>
          <name>F</name>
            <comm>
              <name>D</name>
            </comm>
        </comm>
    </comm>
</comm>
```

Basically, C, E, and F will be siblings and they'll be inside the sections `<comm><name>C/E/F</name></comm>` and then inside that tag will be D. Every element needs to be inside the comm and the name tags.

I have already done the code which looks like this,

```
$basecomm = $doc->createElement( "start" );
$doc->appendChild( $basecomm );
$base = $doc->getElementsByTagName("comm");

foreach($ip as $input){
    $arr=explode("-",$input);


    foreach ($arr as $a){
        $newcomm=null;
        foreach ( $base as $community )   {

            foreach($community->childNodes as $nextElement){
            if ( $nextElement instanceof DOMElement
                    && $nextElement->tagName == 'name' && $nextElement->nodeValue==$a)   {
                        $newcomm = $nextElement->parentNode;
                    }
        }
        }
        if($newcomm==null){
        $newcomm=$doc->createElement("comm");
        $xml_comm_name=$doc->createElement("name",htmlspecialchars($a));
        $newcomm->appendChild($xml_comm_name);
        $basecomm->appendChild($newcomm);
        }
        $basecomm=$newcomm;
}
}
```

My problem is that the entire XML is generating properly but the value D is only appearing as a child of C and not for E and F. So how can I fix my code to do that? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You've already asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46093385/how-to-add-nodes-to-a-multi-level-xml-from-an-array What has changed?

Comment: @u_mulder that previous one I asked since I wanted to know how to name the nodes while building the hierarchy. Here I am working with only the values inside the nodes while the tag names remain unchanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're not checking child elements in the **context of their parent**. So when you check the `D` of `'A-B-E-D'` it's just checking "is there a D". It's not asking "is there a D with parent E". So it thinks the D is already present.

If you reset the set of valid elements to check to the correct parent each time you start from the top of the tree, you should get the right results.

```
<?php
    $ip=["A-B-C-D","A-B-E-D","A-B-F-D","G-H","G-B","X-Y-G-B"];

    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $doc->formatOutput = true;

    $basecomm = $doc->createElement( "start" );
    $doc->appendChild( $basecomm );

    foreach($ip as $input){
        $base = $doc->getElementsByTagName("comm");
        $currentcomm = $basecomm;

        $arr = explode("-", $input);

        foreach ($arr as $k => $a) {
            $parentComm = null;

            foreach ( $base as $x => $community ) {
                foreach ($community->childNodes as $nextElement) {
                    if ($nextElement->tagName == 'name' && $nextElement->nodeValue==$a) {
                        $parentComm = $nextElement->parentNode;
                    }
                }
            }

            if ($parentComm==null){
                $newcomm=$doc->createElement("comm");
                $xml_comm_name=$doc->createElement("name",htmlspecialchars($a));
                $newcomm->appendChild($xml_comm_name);
                $currentcomm->appendChild($newcomm);
                $base = $newcomm->getElementsByTagName("comm");
                $currentcomm = $newcomm;
            } else {
                $base = $parentComm->getElementsByTagName("comm");
                $currentcomm = $parentComm;
            }
        }
    }

    echo $doc->saveXML();
```

This is the output, which I think it what you're after.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<start>
  <comm>
    <name>A</name>
    <comm>
      <name>B</name>
      <comm>
        <name>C</name>
        <comm>
          <name>D</name>
        </comm>
      </comm>
      <comm>
        <name>E</name>
        <comm>
          <name>D</name>
        </comm>
      </comm>
      <comm>
        <name>F</name>
        <comm>
          <name>D</name>
        </comm>
      </comm>
    </comm>
  </comm>
  <comm>
    <name>G</name>
    <comm>
      <name>H</name>
    </comm>
    <comm>
      <name>B</name>
    </comm>
  </comm>
  <comm>
    <name>X</name>
    <comm>
      <name>Y</name>
      <comm>
        <name>G</name>
        <comm>
          <name>B</name>
        </comm>
      </comm>
    </comm>
  </comm>
</start>
```

Comment: Hi but this doesn't work if I am adding another array element like "G-H". Then the structure that is given as the output is not correct.

Comment: That's because you're overwriting the `$basecomm` with a new base. If you keep `$basecomm` as what it should be and use `$currentcomm`in its place, things should be right. See update.

Comment: Okay but this goes back once again to my first problem which is if the array element is a repeat then it is not adding to the proper position. If the last array element is "G-B" instead of "G-H" then once again the B is not getting added to G.

Comment: Essentially you need to combine the two. First, check the current node in the context of its parent. C-D and E-D are different Ds.  Second, don't overwrite the base node, but keep track of the current part of the tree you're working on.

Comment: Would be helpful for me and anyone else reading this answer if you could update the code as well if possible. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Thank you once again! :)